# Google Sheets IF statement merged with concatenate

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the following statement to work.

```
=IF(N3=100, (=concatenate("Text",A3;)), "Result").
```

Keep on coming with an error.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
=IF(N3=100, concatenate("Text",A3), "Result")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do it like:

```
=IF(N3=100, "Text "&A3), "Result")
```